# having trouble to get google maps to load on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Please see my code below, I have worked very hard and have sorted out all my coding to work how I want it too, but for some reason I just can't get it to load the map when you open it up in a browser. Can anyone see where I have gone wrong and guide me to get it work please. Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>County Polygons + Markers w/elapsed time</title>
    <script src="../fiveenglishcounties.js" charset="UTF-8">
      // positioning codes © Copyright 2012 UK Data Service. All rights reserved Creative Commons License https://www.ukdataservice.ac.uk
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map, bounds, geocoder, markers = [], pollies, pinImage, pinColor = '00FF00', defaultPinColor = 'F75850', defaultPin;
      $('#controls input[name="[counties]"]').click(function(){
        var poly = pollies[this.value];
        if(poly.map){
          poly.infowindow.close();
          poly.setMap(null);
          this.checked = false;
        } else {
          poly.setMap(map);
          this.checked = true;
        }
      });

      function elapsed(rfd) {
        var rs = (new Date().getTime() - rfd.getTime()) / 1000,
            days = Math.floor(rs / 86400),
            hours = Math.floor((rs - (days * 86400 )) / 3600),
            minutes = Math.floor((rs - (days * 86400 ) - (hours * 3600 )) / 60),
            secs = Math.floor((rs - (days * 86400 ) - (hours * 3600 ) - (minutes * 60))),
            fet = secs + 's';
        if(minutes){fet = minutes + 'm' + ' ' + fet;}
        if(hours){fet = hours + 'h' + ' ' + fet;}
        if(days){fet = days + ' Day' + (days > 1? 's' : '') + ' ' + fet;}
        return 'Created: ' + rfd.toLocaleTimeString().toLowerCase() + ',<br>' + fet + ' ago';
      }
      function createMarker(latlng, html, map) {
        var ref = $.trim($('#reference').val()),
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: ref || html
            }),
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              time : new Date(),
              position: latlng,
              html: html,
              icon: defaultPin,
              infowindow: infowindow
            }),
            $tm = $('#themarkers').append('<option value="' + html + '" title="' +  infowindow.content + '">' + html + '</option>');
        $tm.get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
        marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
          clearInterval(infowindow.timer);
          infowindow.setContent((ref || html) + '<br>' + elapsed(marker.time));
          $('#supplementwindow').html(infowindow.content).fadeIn();
          infowindow.timer = setInterval(function(){
            infowindow.setContent((ref || html) + '<br>' + elapsed(marker.time));
            $('#supplementwindow').html(infowindow.content);
          }, 300);
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
        marker.addListener('mouseout', function() {
          clearInterval(infowindow.timer);
          infowindow.close();
          $('#supplementwindow').fadeOut();
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          var oe = this.optel;
          $tm.get(0).selectedIndex = $('option', $tm).index(oe);
          $tm.trigger('change');
        });
        marker.optel = $('option', $tm).last();
        $tm.get(0).size = $('option', $tm).length;
        markers.push(marker);
      }
      $('#formcont form').submit(function(e){
        var addresses = $('.address', this);
        addresses = [addresses.eq(0).val(), addresses.eq(1).val()];
        addresses.forEach(function(address, refnum) {
          if (address) {
            geocoder.geocode({
              'address': address
            }, function(results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                createMarker(results[0].geometry.location, address, map, refnum);
                bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
              } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " +  status);
              }
            });
          }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
      });
      $('#activatemarker').click(function(){
        var tm = $('#themarkers'), si = tm.get(0).options.selectedIndex, $o =  $('option', tm).eq(si), i = $o.val();
        if(!i){return;}
        $.each(markers, function(idx, v){
          if(v.html === i){
            v.setIcon(pinImage);
            return false;
          }
        });
      });
      $('#removemarker').click(function(){
        var tm = $('#themarkers'), si = tm.get(0).options.selectedIndex, $o =  $('option', tm).eq(si), i = $o.val();
        if(!i){return;}
        $.each(markers, function(idx, v){
          if(v.html === i){
            v.setMap(null);
            markers.splice(idx, 1);
            return false; }
        });
        $o.remove();
        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        if(markers.length){
          $.each(markers, function(i, v){
            bounds.extend(v.position);
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
        if(markers.length < 2){
          map.setZoom(markers.length? 13 : 8);
        }
        tm.get(0).size = $('option', tm).length;
      });
      $('#themarkers').change(function(){
        this.title = this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].title;
        var i = this.value;
        if(!i){return;}
        $.each(markers, function(idx, v){
          if(v.html === i){
            map.setCenter(v.position);
            map.setZoom(10);
            return false;
          }
        });
        this.size = $('option', $(this)).length;
      });
      $('#showall').click(function(){
        $('#themarkers').get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
        if(!markers.length){
          map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(52.178227, -0.46013));
          map.setZoom(8);
          return;
        }
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        if(markers.length === 1){
          map.setZoom(8);
        }
      });
      function formatCodes(codeString){
        var a = codeString.split(' '), l = a.length, po;
        while(--l > -1){
          po = a[l].split(',');
          a[l] = {lat: +po[1], lng: +po[0]};
        }
        return a;}
      function initMap() {
        pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com /chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + pinColor);
        defaultPin = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + defaultPinColor);
        var p;
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: {lat: 52.178227, lng: -0.4013},
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        pollies = {
          Bedfordshire: {
            paths: BedfordshireCodes,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.15,
            latlng: {lat: 52.002974, lng: -0.465139}
          },
          Bedford: {
            paths: BedfordCodes,
            strokeColor: '#FFC0CB',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FFC0CB',
            fillOpacity: 0.15,
            latlng: {lat: 52.135973, lng: -0.466655}
          },
          Hertfordshire: {
            paths: HertfordshireCodes,
            strokeColor: '#FFFF55',
            strokeOpacity: 0.9,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FFFF55',
            fillOpacity: 0.25,
            latlng: {lat: 51.809782, lng: -0.237674}
          },
          Cambridgeshire: {
            paths: CambridgeshireCodes,
            strokeColor: '#00FF00',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#00FF00',
            fillOpacity: 0.15,
            latlng: {lat: 52.305297, lng: 0.021820}
          },
          Northamptonshire: {
            paths: NorthamptonshireCodes,
            strokeColor: '#0000FF',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#0000FF',
            fillOpacity: 0.15,
            latlng: {lat: 52.272994, lng: -0.875552}
          }
        };
        for(p in pollies){
          var polly = pollies[p];
          polly.paths = formatCodes(polly.paths);
          polly = pollies[p] = new google.maps.Polygon(polly);
          polly.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: p,
            position: polly.latlng
          });
          polly.addListener('click', function(){
            if(this.infowindow.map){
              this.infowindow.close();
            } else {
              this.infowindow.open(map, this);
            }
          });
          polly.setMap(map); }

      }
      function initialize() {
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width:300px; height: 500px; float:right; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; margin: 50px 90px 50px 75px">
      <h1 align="center">Map Search</h1>
      <div id="formcont" style="border:1px solid #ccc; background:#e5e5e5; padding:10px;" align="center" >
        <form>
          <br>
          Location 1 <input type="text" class="address">
          <br>
          <br>
          Location 2
          <input type="text" class="address">
          <br>
          <br>
          Reference
          <input type="text" id="reference">
          <br>
          <br>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div style="position: absolute; right: 170px; top: 365px; border: 1px solid #bbb; padding: 5px;
                  border-radius: 12px;">
        <label>Bedford: <input type="checkbox" checked name="[counties]" value="Bedford"> (pink)</label><br>
        <label>Bedfordshire: <input type="checkbox" checked name="[counties]" value="Bedfordshire"> (red)</label><br>
        <label>Hertfordshire: <input type="checkbox" checked name="[counties]" value="Hertfordshire"> (yellow)</label><br>
        <label>Cambridgeshire: <input type="checkbox" checked name="[counties]" value="Cambridgeshire"> (green)</label><br>
        <label>Northamptonshire: <input type="checkbox" checked name="[counties]" value="Northamptonshire"> (blue)</label>
      </div>
      <div id="dropsandbuttons" style="position: absolute; right: 200px; top: 500px; border: 1px solid #bbb; padding: 5px;
                                       border-radius: 12px;"><select id="themarkers"><option value="">Select Marker</option>
        </select><br>
        <input type="button" id="showall" title="Or Reset if None" value="Show All Markers"><br>
        <input type="button" id="removemarker" title="Remove Selected Marker" value="Remove Marker"><br>
        <input type="button" id="activatemarker" title="Activate Selected Marker" value="Activate Marker">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="supplementwindow" style="border:1px solid #ccc; background:#e5e5e5; align-content:center; float:left; clear: both position:absolute; margin:200px 0px 200px 200px; padding: 5px; border-radius: 12px;" ></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some problem in your code:

1. You need to call `initMap()` in the function `initialize()` - `initMap()` is the function that actually create the map.
2. You didn't set the `BedfordshireCodes` in `paths: BedfordshireCodes` so for now I was commented it.
3. You need to set `height` for the map. In this case I set the height to `100%` so to `html` and `body` but you can specify it with `px`.

**Working code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>County Polygons + Markers w/elapsed time</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height:100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="../fiveenglishcounties.js" charset="UTF-8">
      // positioning codes © Copyright 2012 UK Data Service. All rights reserved Creative Commons License https://www.ukdataservice.ac.uk
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map, bounds, geocoder, markers = [], pollies, pinImage, pinColor = '00FF00', defaultPinColor = 'F75850', defaultPin;
      $('#controls input[name="[counties]"]').click(function(){
        var poly = pollies[this.value];
        if(poly.map){
          poly.infowindow.close();
          poly.setMap(null);
          this.checked = false;
        } else {
          poly.setMap(map);
          this.checked = true;
        }
      });

      function elapsed(rfd) {
        var rs = (new Date().getTime() - rfd.getTime()) / 1000,
            days = Math.floor(rs / 86400),
            hours = Math.floor((rs - (days * 86400 )) / 3600),
            minutes = Math.floor((rs - (days * 86400 ) - (hours * 3600 )) / 60),
            secs = Math.floor((rs - (days * 86400 ) - (hours * 3600 ) - (minutes * 60))),
            fet = secs + 's';
        if(minutes){fet = minutes + 'm' + ' ' + fet;}
        if(hours){fet = hours + 'h' + ' ' + fet;}
        if(days){fet = days + ' Day' + (days > 1? 's' : '') + ' ' + fet;}
        return 'Created: ' + rfd.toLocaleTimeString().toLowerCase() + ',<br>' + fet + ' ago';
      }
      function createMarker(latlng, html, map) {
        var ref = $.trim($('#reference').val()),
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: ref || html
            }),
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              time : new Date(),
              position: latlng,
              html: html,
              icon: defaultPin,
              infowindow: infowindow
            }),
            $tm = $('#themarkers').append('<option value="' + html + '" title="' +  infowindow.content + '">' + html + '</option>');
        $tm.get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
        marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
          clearInterval(infowindow.timer);
          infowindow.setContent((ref || html) + '<br>' + elapsed(marker.time));
          $('#supplementwindow').html(infowindow.content).fadeIn();
          infowindow.timer = setInterval(function(){
            infowindow.setContent((ref || html) + '<br>' + elapsed(marker.time));
            $('#supplementwindow').html(infowindow.content);
          }, 300);
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
        marker.addListener('mouseout', function() {
          clearInterval(infowindow.timer);
          infowindow.close();
          $('#supplementwindow').fadeOut();
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          var oe = this.optel;
          $tm.get(0).selectedIndex = $('option', $tm).index(oe);
          $tm.trigger('change');
        });
        marker.optel = $('option', $tm).last();
        $tm.get(0).size = $('option', $tm).length;
        markers.push(marker);
      }
      $('#formcont form').submit(function(e){
        var addresses = $('.address', this);
        addresses = [addresses.eq(0).val(), addresses.eq(1).val()];
        addresses.forEach(function(address, refnum) {
          if (address) {
            geocoder.geocode({
              'address': address
            }, function(results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                createMarker(results[0].geometry.location, address, map, refnum);
                bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
              } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " +  status);
              }
            });
          }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
      });
      $('#activatemarker').click(function(){
        var tm = $('#themarkers'), si = tm.get(0).options.selectedIndex, $o =  $('option', tm).eq(si), i = $o.val();
        if(!i){return;}
        $.each(markers, function(idx, v){
          if(v.html === i){
            v.setIcon(pinImage);
            return false;
          }
        });
      });
      $('#removemarker').click(function(){
        var tm = $('#themarkers'), si = tm.get(0).options.selectedIndex, $o =  $('option', tm).eq(si), i = $o.val();
        if(!i){return;}
        $.each(markers, function(idx, v){
          if(v.html === i){
            v.setMap(null);
            markers.splice(idx, 1);
            return false; }
        });
        $o.remove();
        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        if(markers.length){
          $.each(markers, function(i, v){
            bounds.extend(v.position);
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
        if(markers.length < 2){
          map.setZoom(markers.length? 13 : 8);
        }
        tm.get(0).size = $('option', tm).length;
      });
      $('#themarkers').change(function(){
        this.title = this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].title;
        var i = this.value;
        if(!i){return;}
        $.each(markers, function(idx, v){
          if(v.html === i){
            map.setCenter(v.position);
            map.setZoom(10);
            return false;
          }
        });
        this.size = $('option', $(this)).length;
      });
      $('#showall').click(function(){
        $('#themarkers').get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
        if(!markers.length){
          map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(52.178227, -0.46013));
          map.setZoom(8);
          return;
        }
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        if(markers.length === 1){
          map.setZoom(8);
        }
      });
      function formatCodes(codeString){
        var a = codeString.split(' '), l = a.length, po;
        while(--l > -1){
          po = a[l].split(',');
          a[l] = {lat: +po[1], lng: +po[0]};
        }
        return a;}
      function initMap() {
        pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com /chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + pinColor);
        defaultPin = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + defaultPinColor);
        var p;
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: {lat: 52.178227, lng: -0.4013},
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        /*pollies = {
          Bedfordshire: {
            paths: BedfordshireCodes,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.15,
            latlng: {lat: 52.002974, lng: -0.465139}
          },
          Bedford: {
            paths: BedfordCodes,
            strokeColor: '#FFC0CB',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FFC0CB',
            fillOpacity: 0.15,
            latlng: {lat: 52.135973, lng: -0.466655}
          },
          Hertfordshire: {
            paths: HertfordshireCodes,
            strokeColor: '#FFFF55',
            strokeOpacity: 0.9,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FFFF55',
            fillOpacity: 0.25,
            latlng: {lat: 51.809782, lng: -0.237674}
          },
          Cambridgeshire: {
            paths: CambridgeshireCodes,
            strokeColor: '#00FF00',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#00FF00',
            fillOpacity: 0.15,
            latlng: {lat: 52.305297, lng: 0.021820}
          },
          Northamptonshire: {
            paths: NorthamptonshireCodes,
            strokeColor: '#0000FF',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#0000FF',
            fillOpacity: 0.15,
            latlng: {lat: 52.272994, lng: -0.875552}
          }
        };
        for(p in pollies){
          var polly = pollies[p];
          polly.paths = formatCodes(polly.paths);
          polly = pollies[p] = new google.maps.Polygon(polly);
          polly.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: p,
            position: polly.latlng
          });
          polly.addListener('click', function(){
            if(this.infowindow.map){
              this.infowindow.close();
            } else {
              this.infowindow.open(map, this);
            }
          });
          polly.setMap(map); }*/

      }
      function initialize() {
        initMap();
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width:300px; height: 500px; float:right; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; margin: 50px 90px 50px 75px">
      <h1 align="center">Map Search</h1>
      <div id="formcont" style="border:1px solid #ccc; background:#e5e5e5; padding:10px;" align="center" >
        <form>
          <br>
          Location 1 <input type="text" class="address">
          <br>
          <br>
          Location 2
          <input type="text" class="address">
          <br>
          <br>
          Reference
          <input type="text" id="reference">
          <br>
          <br>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div style="position: absolute; right: 170px; top: 365px; border: 1px solid #bbb; padding: 5px;
                  border-radius: 12px;">
        <label>Bedford: <input type="checkbox" checked name="[counties]" value="Bedford"> (pink)</label><br>
        <label>Bedfordshire: <input type="checkbox" checked name="[counties]" value="Bedfordshire"> (red)</label><br>
        <label>Hertfordshire: <input type="checkbox" checked name="[counties]" value="Hertfordshire"> (yellow)</label><br>
        <label>Cambridgeshire: <input type="checkbox" checked name="[counties]" value="Cambridgeshire"> (green)</label><br>
        <label>Northamptonshire: <input type="checkbox" checked name="[counties]" value="Northamptonshire"> (blue)</label>
      </div>
      <div id="dropsandbuttons" style="position: absolute; right: 200px; top: 500px; border: 1px solid #bbb; padding: 5px;
                                       border-radius: 12px;"><select id="themarkers"><option value="">Select Marker</option>
        </select><br>
        <input type="button" id="showall" title="Or Reset if None" value="Show All Markers"><br>
        <input type="button" id="removemarker" title="Remove Selected Marker" value="Remove Marker"><br>
        <input type="button" id="activatemarker" title="Activate Selected Marker" value="Activate Marker">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="supplementwindow" style="border:1px solid #ccc; background:#e5e5e5; align-content:center; float:left; clear: both position:absolute; margin:200px 0px 200px 200px; padding: 5px; border-radius: 12px;" ></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/wosebo/edit?html,css,js

Comment: thank you for your response, but now all my other functions do not work. The markers, the county colours on the map and the remove marker/activate marker all don't work?

Comment: Of course it will not work, see section 2. Where do you define `BedfordshireCodes`?

Comment: What do you mean by where do I define it? It is to control the diffrenct colours for the different counties on the map that i can't display. I have noticed that I have forgot to encase the html forms in a <div id='controls'></div>

Comment: How `BedfordshireCodes` looks like? Where it defined? Like `var BedfordshireCodes = ...;`

Comment: is it not defined by this  var map, bounds, geocoder, markers = [], pollies, pinImage, pinColor = '00FF00', defaultPinColor = 'F75850', defaultPin;
      $('#controls input[name="[counties]"]').click(function(){
        var poly = pollies[this.value];
        if(poly.map){
          poly.infowindow.close();
          poly.setMap(null);
          this.checked = false;
        } else {
          poly.setMap(map);
          this.checked = true;
        }
      });
and the use of the html form?

Comment: No, You can see in the [bin](http://output.jsbin.com/resutaf) that `BedfordshireCodes is not defined`. http://i.stack.imgur.com/WeGz6.png

Comment: oh right ok I am not sure what to do about that or how to rectify it

Comment: Where did you get this code? I guess that you didn't wrote this, right?

Comment: no not all of it, I had some help from someone, but It was all working fine until I changed the source of the googlemaps

Comment: I will, but like I said it was all working when he showed me with his api key link, but when I swapped it for mine so I could use it to work on more it stopped working

Comment: I'll have a chat with the other guy, and if i need more help or even get a resaloution i will let you know. Thanks for your help so far